# Some "weird" C code

Tags: c

I have this C code that i'm having problems understanding:

```
int foo(int f(int,int), int g(int,int), int x) {

    int y = g(x,x);
    return f(y,y);
}

int sq(int x, int y) {
    if (x == 1) { return y; }
    return pl(y, sq(x-1, y));
}

int pl(int x, int y) {
    if (x == 0) { return y; }
    return pl(x-1, y+1);
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   printf("sq = %d\n", sq);
   printf("output=%d\n", foo(sq, pl, 1));
   return 0;
}
```

I understood that f is multiplying two variables and g is multiplying, they're apparently built in. The function foo has has two parameters declared as a function declaration -> f(int, int) and g(int, int). But then foo is passed with two arguments - sq and pl. The two arguments have also very strange values - 3392 and 3488, are those logical address of the functions sq and pl? If they are and they are passed as integers, how does foo accepts them? Since foo, has function declaration in place of the parameters where these arguments should go to.

Thank you,
EDIT: cool, thank you guys alot, that cleared things up!

Comment: Is that compiling? I didn't think it was this easy to create a functor without the pointers.. Stupid me, it must be or how would you see "very strange values"

Comment: print the address with `%p`: printf("sq = %p\n", sq);

Comment: foo takes 3 arguments -- two function(int,int) identifiers/pointers and one integer.  The call to foo passes the two functions and one integer.  It's mildly bizarre, but nothing particularly exotic.

Comment: it does compile and prints 4.

Comment: Apparently, it decays to a functor.. learnt something new.. yay!

Comment: @Lews: There's no "decaying" here. There are also no functors in C

Comment: @NiklasB. Right.. Functor is just an object.. *function pointer* then :) What would be the correct term if not decaying?

Comment: `int f(int,int)` is just a way to declare a function pointer inside a function declaration and `f(y,y)` is a way to make an indirect function call using that pointer. Also, the `&` operator is not necessary to get the address of a function.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, what confused me was the lack of *, as I've seen in some tutorials. If not "decay", then an implicit conversion took place as the answers pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f` and `g` are not built in. They are just parameters of the function `foo()`, as you already see.

Besides, `printf("sq = %d\n", sq);` is undefined behaviour, as `sq` is not an integer value, but a function resp. its address in this context. So you should write `printf("sq = %p\n", sq);` in order to cleanly output the address of the function.

What really happens is that you give `foo()` the function `sq` as the parameter `f` and the function `pl` as the parameter `g`. `foo` calls these functions with the parameter `x` as written.

So essentially `foo` calls `pl(1,1)` and stores the result into `y` which is then used for `sq(y,y)`. So it delegates work to these functions. These functions can be seen as callback functions, because `foo()` calls the functions given by the caller.

What `sq()` and `pl()` do is, by now, beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

There's absolutely nothing special about this code. There's nothing "built-in" involved here.

These are ordinary function pointers. In C declaration

```
int foo(int f(int,int), int g(int,int), int x)
```

is automatically interpreted as

```
int foo(int (*f)(int,int), int (*g)(int,int), int x)
```

Functions `sq` and `pl` are passed as arguments to `foo`

```
foo(sq, pl, 1); // same as foo(&sq, &pl, 1)
```

(the `&` operator is optional) and called through these pointers inside `foo`

```
int y = g(x,x); // same as (*g)(x,x)
return f(y,y);  // same as (*f)(y,y)
```

(the `*` operator in the call is optional).

In don't know where you got these `3392` and `3488` values. Function pointers are not "passed as integers". If your debugger decided to display pointer values as `3392` and `3488`, it must be a problem with your debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question and can remember any C then foo is a function that takes *pointers* to 2 functions f and g plus an int, it returns an int.

Both f and g are functions that take 2 ints and return an int.

The number you see is an address of the functions pl and sq, so it looks fine

You need to go and read about passing function pointers as parameters to get a fuller explanation of what is going on, this might help (even though it's C++) http://www.oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/FunctionPointers/Volume/CCPP/FPT/em_fpt.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
int foo(int f(int,int), int g(int,int), int x)
```

declares `foo` as a function taking three arguments, the first two are (pointers to) functions that take two `int`s as arguments and return an `int`, the third argument is an `int`.

`sq` and `pl` are functions of the appropriate type, so the call

```
foo(sq, pl, 1)
```

is correct.